# How to make the scrollBy works directly?

Tags: android, scrollview

Scroll By does not trigger directly. How to do it? Please help. I am a newbie on this. :-(

```
//declaration of my ScrollView

scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollMe);

private View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListenertest = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(myTextBox.hasFocus())
         {
             scroll.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        scroll.scrollBy(0 , +30);
                    }
                });
         }

    }
};
```

Comment: write some thing about your problem or any kind of error you have faced

Comment: I don't have any error faced. My only concern is that, why is it the scroll By method doest not trigger directly?. Please help me.

Comment: when u want to scroll on click of any button or something else

Comment: No I dont want to click. What I want is on every Focus of a textbox I want to scroll. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `myTextBox.hasFocus()` use `v.hasFocus` and also I dont think runnable is required directly call `scroll.scrollBy(0 , +30);`

So your code will be like this

```
  scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollMe);

private View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListenertest = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(v.hasFocus())
     {

                    scroll.scrollBy(0 , +30);//if u get exception or ANR then use Runnable the way u did

     }

}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try this one and I will inform you later. thanks.

Comment: The reason for that I used textbox, so that every focus on the textbox the scroll by will trigger. But thanks again, I will try this first. Hope you will help me for this. T

Comment: I got it now instead of using scroll by I used arrowscroll and fullscroll it is more valuable compared to scrollBy. Thanks God and God Bless to those people give their answers. Thanks.

Comment: your are right I also used fullscroll it worked for me but faced problem while using scrollBy..All the best..keep it up

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks to all of you guyz.I realy appreciate what you did. Thanks and God Bless.